# Racket: Evaluate a hand in Blackjack

Tags: racket

I am trying to create a function in DrRacket that evaluates a blackjack players hand. HOwever, when I used the following code:

```
(define (eval-hand hand)
  (let ([numAces 0] [ttl 0])
    (for/list ([i hand])
      (cond
        [(empty? hand) ttl]
        [(equal? (car i) 'A) (add1 numAces)]
        [(integer? (car i)) (+ (car i) ttl)]
        [else (+ ttl 10)]
        )))
)

(define playerhand '((2 Diamonds) (4 Clubs)))
(display (eval-hand playerhand))
```

I get `(2 4)` as my answer. What am I doing wrong? Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: What were you expecting to get?

Comment: `ttl` is always zero. What is its purpose?

Comment: It looks like you expect `(add1 numAces)` to modify `numAces`, but [`add1`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._add1%29%29) is just a regular addition, so `(add1 numAces)` is always 1. (You also ignore the value of `numAces` completely...) I think your first mistake was reaching for a loop-like structure. Think "how do I turn a list of cards into a list of their integer values" and "how do I add up a list of integers".